# How to change the background color of dropdown list

Tags: oracle-adf

I am new in ADF and my requirement is that when I run the page containing the drop down list input box initially it should be yellow colour with blank input box and after clicking on drop down list then list comes in white background colour. 
After select any value from list again it display the yellow background input box with selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an ADF Skin (ex: https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_learn_adf_skinning). 
You will need to define several StyleClasses for each of your cases and apply that style class when needed.